# Correct HTTP status code to number of items per page exceeded + pagination offset

Tags: rest, http-status-codes, api-design

I have a restriction in my API where the maximum permitted number of items per page is 50.

What is the correct HTTP code to return to consumer if he put 51, for example?

I thought about HTTP 400 (Bad request), because the consumer "knows" (based in API conventions) that the maximum is 50. In this case I will also return a response with the error described.

The same question for pagination. If I have 20 rows/objects and the API consumer put 21 in the offset param, should I return HTTP 200 with total = 0?

Answer (score 6):

This definitely falls into the 4XX categories of HTTP response.

## **For the first scenario:**

I think the post appropriate status for this use case is `400 BAD REQUEST`, based on the HTTP spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)

> 6.5.1.  400 Bad Request
>
> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot
> or    **will not process the request due to something that is perceived
> to be    a client** error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid
> request    message framing, or deceptive request routing).

The user "knows" that API will not accept `> 50` and the server will/would try to fulfil the another request that conforms with the rules of your API.

## **For the second scenario:**

I'm not sure if understood that correctly.

`200 OK` **would** be correct if your API shows all 20 rows/objects instead of **silently saying that the request succeed and there's no objects at all!**

However:

You might consider `404 Not Found` depending on your business rules if the *page* 21 does not exist.

From RFC7231
:

> The 404 (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did
> not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
> willing to disclose that one exists.

---

Maybe you could explain more the second scenario and I'll edit the response accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you are working with **offset** and **limit** in the request and **count** (and perhaps **total**) in the response.
You ask for a maximum number of results (limit) skipping n results from the beginning (offset) and in the response you get the items, and the number of items returned (to facilitate automation).

**The first scenario** should not be an error. It is the same case as the last page (they ask for 50 but you only return remaining).

- You should return HTTP 200 and the field count=50 or the number of records returned.

**The second scenario** could return one of these:

- HTTP 200 with count=0 (total must be allways the same) and no items in the returned list.
- HTTP 400 because invoker asked for an url that is invalid
- HTTP 404 because items to return are not found

I think it's safe to return an error (4xx + error info) in this situation because the offset can be exceeded by one of these assumptions:

- A coding error
- Invoker is not fetching data from begining (no fresh state)
- Invoker ignored pagination data (present on each response)
- You are not using **total** field in the response (which is optional because there are some situations where you can not count all items or simply it's very expensive counting them). In this case, if your last page has the same number of items (count) as the number of items asked for in the request (limit), there is no way to know that this is the last page, so you try another one. In that last request you will get a **count**=0 in the response and you can stop asking for pages. **This case makes it fair to return a 200 code also because the programmer did exactly what you asked for in the API documentation.**

Answer (score 0):

It must be one of the 4xx status codes, as the server is more than capable of supplying more and hasn't failed in any way, so it's a client error.

400 Bad Request doesn't quite fit to me as there's no "error" per-se, you're simply asking for more than is allowed, but in the correct manner.

I'd opt for 405 Method Not Allowed (A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported by that resource).

Although it's vague, and nothing is going to react according to the status code. I'm assuming the consumer will set it up, realise it's not working, check what was returned and see your error message stating too many rows were requested (max 50).

I wouldn't return 200, that implies there are no items to be had, it doesn't suggest an error on their part.

Comment: I have used HTTP 405 in operations that are not supported in a specific resource.

I think that in this case HTTP 405 is not the best status code to represent a different situation, but I agree with you about "you're simply asking for more than is allowed, but in the correct manner."

About the 200 status code, I agree with you again :)

Comment: Here's a list of the codes and their meaning, so peruse through these and see if any stand out to be more fitting to your situation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Comment: Definitely NOT 405 imo: 405 is for when you try, for example, to PUT to a resource that doesn't accept PUT.  The methods in "*Method* Not Allowed" relates to the https methods (POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc.)